# Dynamic group array of objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

i'm trying to find the fastest way to organize a collection of contents to display in my view.

I have two type of contents: small and large. The size of the small type is one block, the size of the large type is two blocks.

My page width can keep just the space for 3 total block, and I don't want free spaces.

I try to display the situation

```
[--,-,--,-,-,-,--,-,-,--,--,-]
```

This is my array, `--` is a large type, `-` is a small type

I need to obtain this visualization

```
--|-
--|-
-|-|-
--|-
--|-
--
```

The first row is easy, I have one large and one small so is ok, i can go to the second row.
Also for the second row I have 2 + 1, so no problem.
For the third row I have small, small and large. Ops, I have space only for 3 block so I have to skip the large (last) and take the first small I find in my array.
The large I skipped go in the forth row with the first small.

The logic is this, is there any way to rearrange my array in a fast an efficient way? Of course every object of my array has an attribute with the type.

Answer (score 0):

A way could be:

1. sort the items by decrementing size
2. pop the first available item
3. iterate to find the first item that fits in the remaining space on the row
4. if there is more space in the row repeat 3
5. go to 2

Answer (score 0):

```
ary = %w(-- - -- - - - -- - - -- -- - -- -- -- -- --)
rows = [[]]

until ary.empty?
  row_length = rows.last.join.length
  case row_length
  when 3
    rows << []
  when 2
    if ary.first == '--'
      # peak ahead and consume next small element
      n = ary.index { |each| each == '-' }
      next rows << [] unless n
      next rows.last << ary.delete_at(n)
    end
  end
  rows.last << ary.shift
end

p rows
```